# Authentication and resource ownership in microservices system

Tags: authentication, authorization, microservices, ownership

I am developing a microservice-based system for managing companies, retailers and their products and contracts. This system should allow users to register, create their company(ies), invite other users to join their company(ies) and, based on the role they have inside the company, manage and see the company's retailers and contracts. Of course, a company can have many retailers and a retailer can handle many contracts on behalf of the company. I came up with a system whose core services are the following:

1. An authentication component that releases JWT tokens that include the user's permissions.
2. A registry component which manages User, Company and Retailer info.
3. A contracts component which handles all data about company contracts and their status.

At the moment the registry component holds models describing users, companies and their retailers, while the contracts component describes all the contracts in the system, with an external reference to the retailer who stipulated the contract.

In this system, only users should authenticate to act on behalf of the company, but companies themselves never authenticate (i.e. the authentication service only holds a reference to the user and his/her permissions). So, a user's token needs to state the permissions the user has with respect to each company he/she belongs to.

Now I find myself with the following dilemma:

> when a user wants to see all contracts for a business, his/her request will be routed to the contracts component. This component can see the user uuid and his/her permissions with respect to every business. However, the contracts component does not know anything about businesses and which business owns which retailer, as these info are handled by the registry component.

Of course, one solution would be the contracts component contacting the registry component and asking for all the retailers for the requested business and comparing that information with the user's clearances stated in the token but this would break services self-containment, hence making the contracts component dependent on the registry component.

Another solution would involve always storing an owner along with the represented resource (i.e. a uuid of the business in every contract from every retailer of the business), but this looks messy and introduces a lot of redundancy.

All in all, my question is: how does one handle resource ownership in a microservices system without creating interdependencies among microservices or relying on a central authority?